# Create a Post API endpoint that takes JSON format and returns a response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, rest

I'm trying to create a (POST) API endpoint that takes the following sample JSON:

```
{ “operation_type”: Enum <addition | subtraction | multiplication> , “x”: Integer, “y”: Integer }
```

The operation can either be addition, subtraction, or multiplication. x can be a number and an integer datatype. y can be a number and an integer datatype. Based on the operation sent, the program performs a simple arithmetic operation on x and y and returns a response with the result of the operation and my slack username

```
{ “slackUsername”: String, "operation_type" : Enum. value, “result”: Integer }
```

Here is what I have done so far

Model

```
String slackUsername = "Ajava";
    Integer x;
    Integer y;
```

Enum

```
public enum Operator  {

    addition,
    subtraction,
    multiplication,
    unknown
}
```

Service

```
public class Service {

    String operation_type;
    String result;
    String username;

    private Operator checkType(String operation_type) {
       Model model = new Model();
        if (operation_type.equals("addition")) {
            username =  model.getSlackUsername();
            var operation = Operator.addition;
         result = String.valueOf(model.getX() + model.getY());

        }else if (operation_type.equals("subtraction")){
            var operation = Operator.subtraction;
            result = String.valueOf(model.getX() - model.getY());

        } else if (operation_type.equals("multiplication")){
            var operation = Operator.multiplication;
            result = String.valueOf(model.getX() + model.getY());

        } else {
            var operation = Operator.unknown;
            result = String.valueOf(model.getX() + model.getY());

        }
        return Operator.valueOf(this.operation_type);
    }

    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    Service service;

    @PostMapping(path = "/operation", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String postOperation() {

return service.operation_type;
    }

    }
```

Comment: are you getting an error? what do you need help with?

Comment: the api starts but I get a 404 error not found when I sent a post request from postman. I need help with refactoring my code to achieve the stated outcome. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rest api end-point can be called. I tried and it did not produce a 404 error. I assume you tried locally. Please check your http request again and check what port the application is running in.

Regarding the solution it had some issues, I have made some fixes and changes,
Refer to this code as an example.
https://github.com/sanurah/rest-example

You can send a post request like this when the service is running,

Sample request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/operation' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "operation_type": "addition",
    "x": 6,
    "y": 4
}'
```

Sample Response:

```
{
    "slackUsername": "Ajava",
    "result": 10,
    "operation_type": "addition"
}
```

Comment: @PlusUltra you only have to update the data type in models and it will work.
Check the code again. I have updated
https://github.com/sanurah/rest-example/commit/06e7a8b9717c576e0cfe439d66be1b4193127aef